# Is there a way to prematurely cause a word break in Javascript or CSS?

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm generating a random string of words, say 15 words. These generated words have the `word-break: normal` style, and we can call this `generatedWords`

I then directly overlay user inputted characters onto `generatedWords`

The overlaying works fine until one of the words in `generatedWords` causes a word-break. For example, we can say that a 5-character long word causes a word break. Then, the user input does not correctly break until reaching 5 characaters, meaning that the two are no longer correctly overlayed

For example, consider the vertical bar as the "bounds" of the div container, and consider lowercase letters as `generatedWords` and uppercase letters as overlayed user input
Take the sample user input "hi hello ver" as an example

```
generated words:     overlayed input (current):   overlayed input(expected):
| hi hello     |     | HI HELLO VER |              | HI HELLO     |
| verylongword |     | verylongword |              | VERylongword |
```

As shown, the line break does not occur until the user types "ver" which causes the user input to overlay onto nothing until the line break occurs

I want to know if it's possible to prematurely cause a word break?

I tried appending white spaces to the user input based on how far away the next white space was in `generatedWords`, but that didn't work as all user input would then have extra white-space characters.

Comment: try using unicode character [U+2800](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+2800) instead of a space for the forced line-break